# What is the difference between `RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT` and `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT`?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, malloc, ruby-2.1

Why does Ruby MRI 2.1 define both `RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT` and `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [great resource](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-rgengc/) to explain this concept.

In brief, the reason there are two `MALLOC_LIMIT` variables is that Ruby 2.1 has moved to a two-generation garbage collector. When the memory footprint of newer high-turnover objects on the heap reaches the `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT`, it triggers a minor GC event; when the size of longer-lived objects reaches `RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT`, a major GC event is triggered.